# Return a Javascript array to action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here's my problem:
i have a JS array that i want to pass it to an action and then render that action's View. 
this is my array and i fill it Using Jquery like so :

```
    var factorlist = [];
    factorlist.push({ ID: data.ID, Name: data.Name, number: data.number, SingelPrice: data.SingelPrice, TotalPrice: data.TotalPrice })
    (data come from an AJAX Call)
```

then i put a hidden input element in my page to put my array in it and send it with a submit.
here is hidden input and submit button :

```
    <input type="submit" id="input" name="input" />     
    <input type="hidden" id="list" name="list"/>
```

This is how i send it :

```
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        $('#list').val(JSON.stringify(factorlist));

    });
```

and this is the action that i'm sending the array to :

```
     public ActionResult PrePayment(List<Order> list)
    {            
        return View(list);
    }
```

and my order class :

```
     public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public float SingelPrice { get; set; }
    public float TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

**Now the thing is i get and empty list in action not null...what is the problem and is there any other way to do this?  **

Comment: Why involve ajax if you're submitting a form?

Comment: Where Did i use ajax??!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default MVC data binding will not work for you in this case, you have to deserialize your values manually:

```
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
list = (Order[])js.Deserialize(Request.Form["list"], typeof(Order[]));
```

To avoid doing this every time you can register a Custom Model Binding for that type too, check an example in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Json` instead of `JS array`. More details
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right, you want to post your js array from form to controller action, so basing on this [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) there is a solution:

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
    $(factorlist).each(function (i, el) {
        $('form').append($('<input />', {
            type: 'hidden',
            name: 'list[' + i + '].ID',
            value: el.ID
        }));

        // and so on for each your of objects property

    });

});
```

More correct way is to do it using ajax and redirect on success callback.